# Creating a .devcontainer repository

Tags: vscode-remote

We have a number of standard devcontainer configurations that we wanted to publish in an internal repository.  The Remote-Container extension has a configuration for this (Repository Configuration Paths), but I am unable to find any documentation on the format of the repository. Is there guidance on this somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Connect to multiple containers
Currently you can only connect to one container per Visual Studio Code window. However, you can spin up multiple VS Code windows to attach to them.

source: https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/connect-multiple-containers

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, quite old question, but stumbled upon this question while looking for an answer as well.

I think the documentation part you are looking for is this one: [Add configuration files to a repository: Alternative: Repository configuration folders](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/create-dev-container%5C%5C%5C%5C#_alternative-repository-configuration-folders)